# generate null values instead of zeroes

Tags: sql, postgresql

how i will put null values in place of dataset containing zeroes in place of missing values. can you help me with the solutuion?

in the new dataset the missing values were replaced by zeroes instead of null values. what function i should choose to put null values ?

Comment: how null got replaced with zeros in the first place?

Comment: You can use the `NULLIF` function

Answer (score 0):

What is dataset?
If it is a table with a column where values (some of them) are 0 and you want to change them to null then:

```sql
Update your_table_name
Set your_column_name = null
Where your_column_name = 0;  -- or some other filter that you might need
```

If dataset is result of some query then maybe something like...

```sql
Select ID, COL_1, COL_2, COL_X,
       Case When column_with_zero_value = 0   -- and/or some other condition you might need
            Then Null 
       Else column_with_zero_value
       End as column_with_zero_value
From your_table_name;
```

... and if you want all null values in query result then...

```sql
Select ID, COL_1, COL_2, COL_X, null  as your_column_name_with_null_values
From your_table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does Generate mean here? you are looking for a Select statement that replaces if the value is zero to Null. If yes Check this.
Use Case Statement in SQL.

SELECT product_name,
CASE
WHEN price = 0 THEN NULL ELSE price
END
FROM products;